# How to get current time in CP when using Intervals for scheduling

Tags: scheduling, cplex, job-scheduling, constraint-programming, cp-optimizer

I am trying to schedule tasks in different machines. These machines have dynamique available ressources, for example:

machine 1: max capacity 4 core.

At T=t1 => available CPU = 2 core;

At T=t2 => available CPU = 1 core;

Each interval has a fixed time (Ex: 1 minute).

So in CPLEX, I have a cumulFunction to sum the used ressource in a machine :

```
cumulFunction cumuls[host in Hosts] = 
   sum(job in Jobs) pulse(itvs[task][host], requests[task]);
```

Now the problem is in the constraint:

```
forall(host in Hosts) {
    cumuls[host] <= ftoi(available_res_function[host](**<<Current Period>>**));
}
```

I can't find a way to get the current period so that I could compare the used ressources to the available in that specefic period.

PS: available_res_function is a stepFunction of the available ressources.

Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: What do you mean by <<current period>>?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is to add a set of pulse in your cumul function.

For instance, in the sched_cumul function you could change:

```
cumulFunction workersUsage = 
   sum(h in Houses, t in TaskNames) pulse(itvs[h][t],1);
```

into

```
cumulFunction workersUsage = 
   sum(h in Houses, t in TaskNames) pulse(itvs[h][t],1)+pulse(1,40,3);
```

if you want to mention that 3 workers less are available between time 1 and 40.

Comment: Thank you for your answer,
But I don't see how this would solve my problem, I don't have a min and max values.
each period i have diffrent available ressources that I should respect, so if I schedule a job that would run for 3 periods, it has to respect all of the available ressources, that's why I need this constraint:
**
forall(host in Hosts) {
    cumuls[host] <= ftoi(available_res_function[host](**<<Current Period>>**));
}
**

Comment: Hi, you may also use alwaysIn , see https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=851a4aa8-f387-4a0e-94eb-f514839a42b7 for an example

Comment: Amazing, this is exactly what I was looking for, thank you so much sir.